# import a PATSTAT csv into SAS

Tags: csv, sas

When I import `TLS201_APPLN.csv` form PATSTAT database into SAS 9.4 (Unicode support), a lot of similar codes showed like below. What should I do to fix it?

```
NOTE: Invalid data for appln_nr_original in line 5286 53-65.
RULE:     ----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7----+----8----+---
5286      6697,AT,2007000486,W ,2007-10-17,2007,WO2007AT00486,AT2007/000486,PI,0,Y,N,N,2006-12-22,
      89  2006,1110640,2008-07-03,2008,6698,0,38109624,4532,10,2,2,1 146
appln_id=6697 appln_auth=AT appln_nr=2007000486 appln_kind=W appln_filing_date=2007-10-17
appln_filing_year=2007 appln_nr_epodoc=WO2007AT00486 appln_nr_original=. ipr_type=PI
internat_appln_id=0 int_phase=Y reg_phase=N nat_phase=N earliest_filing_date=2006-12-22
earliest_filing_year=2006 earliest_filing_id=1110640 earliest_publn_date=2008-07-03
earliest_publn_year=2008 earliest_pat_publn_id=6698 granted=0 docdb_family_id=38109624
inpadoc_family_id=4532 docdb_family_size=10 nb_citing_docdb_fam=2 nb_applicants=2 nb_inventors=1
_ERROR_=1 _N_=5285
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where's your import code?  You need to fix the code to account for apln_nr_original correctly. It looks like it's a character variable, but has been assigned missing so for some reason you're trying to read it in as numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the import to correctly ready in `apln_nr_original`.

Note the bolded sections below.

So I counted out the number of variables and I think it's the 8th variable, which looks like it should be, AT2007/000486 from the record. However, SAS has it as ., which means it thinks it should be a numeric, when it's actually a character variable. So you need to modify your code to account for that. I'd suggest how to do that but you didn't include any code.

NOTE: Invalid data for **appln_nr_original** in line 5286 53-65.
RULE:     ----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7----+----8----+---
5286      6697,AT,2007000486,W ,2007-10-17,2007,WO2007AT00486,**AT2007/000486**,PI,0,Y,N,N,2006-12-22,
      89  2006,1110640,2008-07-03,2008,6698,0,38109624,4532,10,2,2,1 146

appln_id=6697 
appln_auth=AT 
appln_nr=2007000486 
appln_kind=W 
appln_filing_date=2007-10-17
appln_filing_year=2007 
appln_nr_epodoc=WO2007AT00486 
**appln_nr_original=.** 
ipr_type=PI